# What would be the most optimized way to store really large number of rows in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, optimization, query-optimization, sql-optimization

I have this use case:

3 Tables: `Customers`, `Users`, `Contacts`.
Each customer might have around 10.000 Users.

Each user will have around 15.000 contacts.
I want to store, for each user, their 15.000 contacts in the Contacts table. However, this, with only one customer, sets me at 150 million rows. What if I have 100 customers?

I know Partitioning tables might help, but is there a better option?
What would be the best solution to store this amount of data, and for it to be usable afterwards (Select, Insert queries to be optimized).

Thank you!

Comment: What makes you believe this is a large number of rows?

Comment: 150 million rows shouldnt be an issue?

Comment: 150M rows is *not* a large number of rows. Partitioning is probably the *easiest* way to manage large amounts of data - it's completely transparent to the application. If your customers are actually tenants, partitioning along CustomerId will actually keep a single customer's data together. `A better option` better according to what criteria?

Comment: This is really a database management question, better asked at https://dba.stackexchange.com, but you should also have more specifics before you ask this question as it cannot be answered in the general way that you have posed it.  The specifics you will need are things like estimated total sizes, available configuration, your budget, expected usage, performance targets, etc.

Comment: @DougCoats, this is for 1 customer. What if I have 100? That sets me at 1.5 billion rows. That definitely is an issue.

Comment: I would be highly surprised if none of the Contacts overlap, given that there aren't 15bln people in the world. It would be better to normalize it so you have a `UserContact` many-to-many join table

Comment: @Charlieface, the `Contact` table is actually the many-to-many join table. To be more clear, for one customer, I have a `Users` table (containing 1000 rows), `Contacts` table (containing 15K rows), and the `ContactsCache` (or User-Contacts) Table (the many-to-many table) that will have 1000*15K rows. Every user will *necessarily* have all the 15K contatcs.

Answer (score 1):

The numbers of rows you mention should not require any extraordinary table design.

To keep performance good, avoid large-object column data types like TEXT, LONGTEXT unless you absolutely need them. Instead use NVARCHAR(255) or whatever makes most sense in your application.

Your tables will need the correct indexes to get best performance. To find those indexes, once you have populated your tables with at least some data, you can use SSMS: Before you run the query in SSMS, right-click in the query panel and choose Show Actual Execution Plan.  Then run the query. SSMS will sometimes suggest an index for the query at the top of the execution plan.

It's impossible to guess correct indexes without knowing what your most frequently used queries are. One thing is sure: adding single-column indexes on lots of columns is probably not helpful.

As SQL applications -- like yours -- grow and add users the tables grow. And, it is very common for the tables to need new indexes as they grow. It's completely normal to add or change indexes to applicatios that are in production. Revisit your indexing at 100K rows, then again at a million, ten million, and so forth.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, if I have 100 customers, that sets me at 1.5B rows. That would still be OK? Knowing that my table will only have 4 columns: Id, CustomerId (int), UserId (int), ContactId (int), Status (Int). I still think I should partition it.

Comment: Yes, 1.5 gigarows is well within the capability of SQL Server. At this stage keep it simple. It is a long and winding road from application launch to 100 enterprise-level customers with 10K users each. My hard-won experience teaches me you cannot yet imagine the actual usage patterns of those enterprise customers.  I strongly suggest you spend your time and money on making your app astonishingly useful, not on trying to build for a capacity you don't yet need. Seriously. Plus, partitioning slows things down unless your query patterns match your partition scheme precisely.